# Downloading a file with html anchor tag fails for "Failed - No file"

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, axios

When trying to add `<a href="/someUrl" download="amr.amr">Download</a>`, I get "Failed - No file":
[image]

But when I just get the file content with axios library and the exactly same url(`axios.get('/someUrl')`), I get a valid file stream with response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 317094
vary: Cookie
server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.7.5
date: Sun, 27 Sep 2020 12:17:53 GMT
connection: keep-alive
```

What can be the source of the problem? And how can I debug the anchor tag download part?

Comment: It fails when you click on the link?

Comment: @GProst yes, it happens when I click the link

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="amr.amr"` header for your response. See the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).